# Power Pivot Measure SUMIFS

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have this setup:

```
date                          cost
22 march 2018                  100
10 january 2018                20
15 march 2019                  150
12 january 2019                133
```

I don't know in advance, which cost, dates or how many rows I'll have.

Need a measure that takes this criteria into consideration:
- IF the month is the same as the max month, then, sum the cost of that month until the max day.

The cost for january 2018 would display 20 and all the remaining months would remain equal except for MARCH 2018, because it only sums cost until the max day of the max month (12).

Is this possible to achieve with a measure?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEcVD.png

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you are speaking about a year to date calculation :

you can therefore use this formula :

TOTALYTD(Expression;Date)

[All Explaination can be found here](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2018/08/10/the-hidden-secrets-of-totalytd/)

Comment: Basically, the current year (2019, is always going to be unchanged), but, for the previous year, one of the months is changed. If the current year max month is February, then, for the previous year, February should only be counted until the same day as the current month.

Comment: The reason for that is that we want to compare last year month with current year month, counting the same days that have passed in the current year. Is that possible with this formula?